# How to get type face style of a custom font in android?

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, custom-font, android-fonts

After using custom fonts, I can't get type face style (BOLD, ITALIC, BOLD_ITALIC) of a text view by :

```
textView.getTypeface.getStyle();
```

In fact setting new type face style doesn't apply to textView really, although we can see the style is changing visually. I set type face style like this:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "sampleFont.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(font, Typeface.BOLD);
```

But,

```
textView.getTypeface.getStyle();
```

returns 0 (NORMAL) instead of 1 (BOLD)!
All these happen when I trying to use a regular font.

Answer (score 0):

[`Typeface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) also has the methods [`isBold()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#isBold()) and [`isItalic()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#isItalic()) since API level 1.

Or try this

```
if(textView.getTypeface()!=null){
   if(textView.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.BOLD || textView.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.ITALIC){
      //your code goes here
   }
}
```